# How to interpret a Java thread stack on SMPP protocol?

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, socket.io, smpp

I have found that my application gets hang and does not read data from socket every few hours. In thead dump, i have found below stack trace.

```
"Receiver-146" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fb3fc010000 nid=0x7642 runnable [0x00007fb5906c5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.
socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
        - locked <0x00000007688f1ff0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at org.smpp.TCPIPConnection.receive(TCPIPConnection.java:413)
        at org.smpp.ReceiverBase.receivePDUFromConnection(ReceiverBase.java:197)
        at org.smpp.Receiver.receiveAsync(Receiver.java:351)
        at org.smpp.ReceiverBase.process(ReceiverBase.java:96)
        at org.smpp.util.ProcessingThread.run(ProcessingThread.java:199)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I am not able to  trace the exact reason behind this? please suggest.

Comment: are you sure the socket has some input to read?

Comment: this is a SMPP connection to remote server port. When the issue comes, i see data on Recv-Q of a server. We are using Linux servers (ubantu).

Comment: The thread is blocked in the read method waiting for data to arrive.

Comment: Thanks EJP for ur revert. What should i do to resolve it?

Comment: If the thread wa blocked it would not have RUNNABLE state. Since it is RUNNABLE it actually reading something, but maybe the reading is slow for some reason. Did you check the CPU usage at that time? Maybe the garbage collection process starts which slows down whole application? Try logging with jconsole and see what other threads are doing at that time.

Comment: @walkeros That's not correct. From the JVM's point of view it is RUNNABLE. However from the operating system's point of view it is blocked in `recv().` There is no `Thread.State` value for that.

Comment: @SagarPatel Nothing. Wait for the data to arrive. Probably part of the message has arrived and the rest is still in flight or being created at the peer.

Comment: @EJP ok.. I get your point now, you meant the system thread not java Thread. I agree than with yours suggestion. I meant the same by saying that the "reading is slow for some reason".

Comment: We are using 16 core machine and load on the system is around 30-40 at the time of issue. We use command "ss dst <ip>" to find out recv-q.
Recently we have been facing issues with recv-q size getting hung, were in receive buffer gets stuck at some point of time. But recvQ size is not decreasing and as a result we are losing a lot of hits from the other side, our application is not accepting any data.

Comment: @walkeros I don't think you do get it. The thread is blocked. GC has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @EJP: I pointed GC as it can influence the speed of reading data from socket as it engages CPU and jvm. I did not say it has antyhing to do with blocking the thread. And from jvm perspective the thread is not blocked, as it is reading the data by calling socketRead0().

Comment: @SagarPatel can you paste whole thread dump somwhere (including all running threads)?

Comment: Hi Walkeros,i have uplaoded file to http://www.filedropper.com/thread20aug20141

Comment: @SagarPatel: From first look at the dump I see that you might have problems with memory (just a first guess) since your object space is filled in 98%. I would test implementation of your application against memory leakage. Try following thing: periodicaly call "jmap -histo pid" to see current usage of memory. This way you can observe how your application consumes memory while it runs (if some objects use more and more memory without releasing it). Also add  following jvm param  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError which will create heap dump which can by used for analysis in case of OutOfMemory err